# display fetch data in a flatlist React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

how could i display some fetched data in a flatlist, knowing that it contains nested array, the data looks like this:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "calendar": Array [],
    "profil": Object {
      "id": 9,
      "identifier": "centre",
      "js": false,
      "name": "Labogamma",
      "speciality": false,
      "work": "8 avenue ElManar 1er étage",
    },
  },
]
Array [
  Object {
    "calendar": Array [],
    "profil": Object {
      "id": 9,
      "identifier": "centre",
      "js": false,
      "name": "Labogamma",
      "speciality": false,
      "work": "8 avenue ElManar 1er étage",
    },
  },
]
.
.
.
```

its a long data and i'm using a flatlist, so i can display every name existing:

```
<FlatList 
                data={this.state.dataSource}
                keyExtractor={item=> { return item.id.toString()}}
                renderItem= {({item})=> <Text> *i want to render the names here*</Text>} 
                />
```

i'll apreciate your help.thank you!

Comment: Try ```<Text>{item[0].profil.name}</Text>```

Comment: thanks for your reply, i tried it,i got Typo Error: undefined is not an object(item[0].profil)

Comment: Do you still have this problem?

Comment: Unfortunatly yes, i still do

Comment: could you share your ```this.state.dataSource``` value?

Comment: i use fetch to get data Source: fetchLien(*************
    ).then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      this.setState({
        dataSource:res,
      })
    })

Comment: DataSorce is what described above in the problem

Comment: Then ```<Text>{item[0].profil.name}</Text>``` this should work. if not place ```console.log``` inside your ```renderItem``` function and check the value.

Comment: i did this:  renderItem={({ item }) => console.log(item[0].profil.name)}, i got Typo Error: undefined is not an object(item[0].profil)

Comment: Did you wait until the data load? according to issue ```item[0]``` doesn't have ```profil```. try to debug using ```console.log(item[0])```.

Comment: So i did use console.log(item[0]), it renderer undefined, + my dataSource

Comment: consol.log worked when i did this: renderItem={({ item }) =>{if(item.length>0){ console.log(item[0].profil.name)}}}

Comment: That's because of your render method call before data loads.

Comment: can you please explain more what i did wrong?

Comment: basically this happens because you are trying to get data from an object ```item[0].profil``` was not created yet.

Comment: yeah but code wise, is it due to putting fetch in componentdidmount? or something else?